# MS Analytics Services (SSAS) created cube can not be accessed

Tags: visual-studio, ssms, ssas, cube

I try to learn OLAP techniques and follow a course on udemy. I imported the AdventrueWorks DB into SSMS (Servertyp: Database engine) and conected this database to my Visual Studio MS Analytics Service Project (SSAS).

In MS VS, i can link the DB as Datasource (localhost, connection test ok), i can create a view on the DB an it shows the relevant Keys and Dimentions. I even can create a cube on the view. When i then try to us the Bowser an error occures which says (translated):

> Either the user "User" can not access the database "projectname" or the database doesn't exists

I changed the seetings of all relevant files to unlimted access and gave my user admin-rights as roles inside MS VS. Unfortunatly, its still the same error.

Any idea how to solve this issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to first [deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-tutorial/lesson-2-5-deploying-an-analysis-services-project) the solution from Visual Studio to a server. The “server” could be your local machine if you have an instance running of Analysis Services Multidimensional. After deployment the Browser tab should begin working after you click the reconnect button in the top left.